# ARToolkit examples with Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, artoolkit

i've been trying to open and compile ArToolkit examples from Android Studio 2.2, Example: build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    ...

    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

logs

[image]

Comment: Your library seems to be compiled with Java 8 and you've set Java 7.

Comment: Is that your whole gradle file?

Comment: We need more information about that. I just updated to the latest version from GitHub and imported the ARSimpleProj was able to build without an issue.